Splitting LGPL License into certain folders/files
So my project tree is
Root:

Client

Java


Server

C


LICENCE
README.md 
and I licensed it under LGPL v2.1, so my question is, Is it possible to put the LICENCE inside Server/C and inside Client/Java (And Say that Readme.md is under LGPL v 2.1), and that i would put another folder inside Client (eg Client/Csharp ) and license the latter in a different License?


As this seems to be a common misconception: how you lay out your files in a filesystem or repository fundamentally has no bearing on their licensing. Assuming you are the copyright holder, you can license anything you create in any way you wish.
That said, it is good practice to make the licenses of things you create clear - if you do have mixed licenses in one project and are able to split files with different licenses into different directories, then that is a good and common way to make it clear to consumers which license(s) they need to comply with to use each bit of the project.

So i can do what i said, just that in the LICENSE that is in the main root must explain the licensing on each subdirectory properly?

You do not have to do that. You may if you wish.

Another way is to add license information to each file and all the licence text in a LICENSES directory - see REUSE https://reuse.software
